# Django CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-csrf

So we deployed Django app to Heroku and everything was working well. Until I looked at cookies. I have `csrftoken` cookies for both `app-staging.herokuapp.com` and `.app-staging.herokuapp.com`. But when I set `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'app-staging.herokuapp.com'` I automatically get the wrong thing `.app-staging.herokuapp.com`.

I tried everything I could but nothing helped. I tried current Firefox (83.0) and Chromium. The biggest problem is invalid check for CSRF token. Since domains don't match it's invalid.

```
csrftoken=E9sdyx5U61IaFP3YNJHk3ZKtnllkEnyZ6i9eimHYD31sn4qXRXv7FBDOpPfpWhyt; Domain=app-staging.herokuapp.com; expires=Fri, 19 Nov 2021 15:33:52 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax; Secure
```

Please don't suggest that I set `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None`. In case one Django instance would run on more domains I would need to solve the same problem. Which we will have to do soon.

Answer (score 0):

I did little bit of digging down and got stuck on csrf middleware, refer to the code bellow. There the `good_referer` is set to `app-staging.herokuapp.com:49461`, but the `referer.netloc` is only `app-staging.herokuapp.com`, so the function `is_same_domain` won't match them as then it throws the error: `Referer checking failed - app-staging.herokuapp.com does not match any trusted origins."`

```
good_referer = (
    settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN
    if settings.CSRF_USE_SESSIONS
    else settings.CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN
)
if good_referer is not None:
    server_port = request.get_port()
    if server_port not in ('443', '80'):
        good_referer = '%s:%s' % (good_referer, server_port)
else:
    try:
        # request.get_host() includes the port.
        good_referer = request.get_host()
    except DisallowedHost:
        pass

# Create a list of all acceptable HTTP referers, including the
# current host if it's permitted by ALLOWED_HOSTS.
good_hosts = list(settings.CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS)
if good_referer is not None:
    good_hosts.append(good_referer)

if not any(is_same_domain(referer.netloc, host) for host in good_hosts):
    reason = REASON_BAD_REFERER % referer.geturl()
    return self._reject(request, reason)
```

Source:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py#L262